# How to find the pole of a equation where the residue exist？

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

I want to calculate the residue of an equation, such as:

```
equ = 1/((x - 2)Sqrt[x - 1])
```

So first I need to find the pole of the equation. My method is find the root of `Denominator[equ] == 0`:

```
pole = Solve[Denominator[equa] == 0, x]
```

and the solutions are

```
{{x -> 1}, {x -> 2}}
```

But obviously, the equation has no residue at `x = 1` because its order is 1/2.

[image]

How can I automatically find the pole of the equation where the residue exists? Or, alternatively, how to find the pole whose order is an integer?

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
r[x_] := 1/((x - 2) Sqrt[x - 1])

Select[x /. Solve[Denominator[r[x]] == 0, x],
       SeriesCoefficient[r[x], {x, #, -1}] != 0 &]
   {2}
```

Or a more direct solution (with thanks to xzczd):

```
Select[x /. Solve[Denominator[r[x]] == 0, x],
       FreeQ[Residue[r[x], {x, #}], _Residue] &]
```