# How to detect discontinuous point in a symbolic function?

Tags: plotting, symbolic

Mathematica `Plot` function can detect exclusion points automatically. How was that realized? How can I generalize that to included discontinuity of `DiracDelta` functions as well?

For example, I would like to have something like

```
ExclusionPoints[UnitStep[x + 2] + DiracDelta[x - 1] + Piecewise[{{1, x > 0}}], x]
(* returns {-2, 0, 1} *)
```

Comment: see related [does-mathematica-have-a-function-to-find-all-singularities-of-an-expression](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/135946/does-mathematica-have-a-function-to-find-all-singularities-of-an-expression) but solution there does not work on your expression. I think it does not like the `DiracDelta`

Comment: `FunctionDomain` seems to work for mathematical expressions that do not involve some special functions (e.g., `HeavisideTheta[x]` or `DiracDelta[x]`).